# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified when using Calculated ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have seen a few responses to this common error but none that fit my particular query.

I am receiving 'ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified'

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 40 LocatorID, DisplayAddress 
FROM [UKStreetsAndPlaces].[dbo].[OS_Locator] 
WHERE (SearchAddress LIKE 'Bal%') 
ORDER BY (Longitude + 0.537143) * (Longitude + 0.537143) + (Latitude - 51.253741) * (Latitude - 51.253741) ASC
```

I have tried adding the Latitude and Longitude fields into the SELECT line and I have tried adding GROUP BY for these fields also but I get the same error.

Comment: Consider this - a particular `LocatorID, DisplayAddress` combination may exist for *multiple* rows, but those rows are reduced down to 1 by the `DISTINCT` - so how is the database server meant to know *which* row's `Latitude` and `Longitude` values should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your order by items into your select statement. i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 40 LocatorID, DisplayAddress, 
(Longitude + 0.537143) * (Longitude + 0.537143) + (Latitude - 51.253741) * (Latitude - 51.253741) as MyPosition 
FROM [UKStreetsAndPlaces].[dbo].[OS_Locator] 
WHERE (SearchAddress LIKE 'Bal%') 
ORDER BY (Longitude + 0.537143) * (Longitude + 0.537143) + (Latitude - 51.253741) * (Latitude - 51.253741) ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead use `group by` and aggregation functions.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT TOP 40 LocatorID, DisplayAddress 
FROM [UKStreetsAndPlaces].[dbo].[OS_Locator] 
WHERE (SearchAddress LIKE 'Bal%') 
GROUP BY LocatorID, DisplayAddress 
ORDER BY MIN((Longitude + 0.537143) * (Longitude + 0.537143) + (Latitude - 51.253741) * (Latitude - 51.253741)) ASC;
```

Comment: This works until I add the DISTINCT back into the statement and then I get the error 'ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.' again?

Comment: @ChrisCurrie . . . You don't need the `DISTINCT`.  There is a `GROUP BY`.